# How to find the Volume of Dubai's Museum of the Future (An ellipsoid with an ellipsoidal hole in it)?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm an IB Mathematics HL student doing a math research report for school, I need to be able to model [Dubai's Museum of the Future building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PpOi.jpg). Do you know how I could model this shape mathematically and find its volume? I was thinking ellipsoid minus another smaller ellipsoid for the hole in the middle but the edges wouldn't make sense? Thanks for any help!

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_mesh

Comment: The hole is not an ellipsoid.